# Where the summer is cold?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Never Let Me Go](https://books.google.com/books?id=JAzxznMKiq4C&pg=PA107&lpg=PA107&dq=chilly%20%22outside%20the%20summer%20months%22&source=bl&ots=65PwzKxabt&sig=ACfU3U1eYXEPNMu7nC8r8o6IsyHqpImYvA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiLyriK2IPjAhV4FjQIHeP3BN4Q6AEwDXoECAkQAQ)

> So I remember a lot of the time, outside the **summer** months, being
>   **chilly**. You went around with two, even three jumpers on, and your
>   jeans felt cold and stiff.

I wonder, why is the outdoor chilly in the summer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, **outside** is not referring to the outdoors. It is referring to months that are **not** summer. These months are considered "outside" of the group of months labelled under **summer**

It conveying the meaning of "besides the summer months" or "not in the summer months".

Another example would could be

> "Outside the technical subjects, my favorite class is creative writing".

This would imply that the speaker generally likes most technical subjects a lot. But besides those subjects, her most liked subject is creative writing.

Comment: However, *outside **in** the summer months* would have meant outdoors in the summer.